# Use variables in between classes in python

Tags: python, class, variables

Im having some problem importing one variable between classes i have just something like this:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dosomething():
    def dosomething(self):
        x = [99, 98]
        return x

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        y = Class1()
        print y
```

At the end I would like to be able to use x into Class2
but my example i just get:

```
<myfile.Class1 instance at 0x.....>
```

any way to be able to use "x" in Class2 or another solution ?

could be solution to use a global variable?

```
globalx = []
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dosomething():
    def dosomething(self):
        x = [99, 98]
        globalx = x
        return x

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        y = globalx
        print y
```

Comment: There's no way to do that. What are you trying to accomplish? Your example is unclear.

Comment: y is an instance of Class1. `y.x` refers to the field x of instance y. Also, your x is local to `dosomething`, you'd need to call it `self.x` to make it publicly visible.

Comment: `print y.dosomething()`

Comment: @Mephy no, `y.x` refers to `Class1`'s `self.x`, which is not found

Comment: @TimCastelijns that only works if his real functions are as simplistic as his examples. I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: @AdamSmith He should have used an example better reflecting the real code then ;-)

Comment: in the real code (is quite long) but basically is the same situation, I obtain a list in Class1 and need to use the same list in Class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = self.dosomething()

    def dosomething(self):
        return [99, 98]

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        y = Class1()
        print y.x
```

But it depends on how complex the operation in the real `dosomething()` actually is. You might want your `dosomething()` to be a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) etc. I will improve the answer if you add more detail.